# PHP Update a Session Value Based on Another Session Value

Tags: php, session

I am trying to update a session value(`$_SESSION['adtitle']`) based on another session value(`$_SESSION['amount']`) with following code.It works for first time page load but then after it doesn't update the session accordingly though my main session `$_SESSION['amount']` is updating

```
<?php
 session_start();
 if (isset($_SESSION['amount'])) {

 if($_SESSION['amount']=2)
 $_SESSION['adtitle']="Premium Listings for $2";

 else if ($_SESSION['amount']=4)
 {$_SESSION['adtitle']="Premium Blogs for $4";}

 } else {
 $_SESSION['adtitle']="Pls select your purchase type again!!";
 }
 header('Location: '. $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'] . '');
?>
```

Comment: You forget the second "=" on your statements.

Comment: `if ($_SESSION['amount']=2)` needs to be `if ($_SESSION['amount'] == 2)`, and same for the other `if` as well. `=` sets a value, whereas `==` and `===` compare values.

Comment: changed but same result. first time it works then after it doesn't update though $_SESSION['amount'] value is changed

Answer (score 0):

missing `=` on comparison. I have fixed the issue

```
<?php
 session_start();
 if (isset($_SESSION['amount'])) {

 if($_SESSION['amount']==2)
 $_SESSION['adtitle']="Premium Listings for $2";

 else if ($_SESSION['amount']==4)
 {$_SESSION['adtitle']="Premium Blogs for $4";}

 } else {
 $_SESSION['adtitle']="Pls select your purchase type again!!";
 }
 header('Location: '. $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'] . '');
?>
```

Comment: changed it accordingly but yet same result for first time it updates then after it doesn't